# Dynamic Button and event with data - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am pretty new to AngularJS. I am working on a scenario which reads a file and display it on the table in web page.

When process button is clicked, each record in the table is processed. A field in the table then either becomes Failure or change to a button "View Result".

Below is the part that doesn't work:
"On clicking view result, the data should on a table in pop-up or bottom of current page. This data is dynamic. Meaning each "View Result" button will have different data."

I am facing 2 issues: 
1. On clicking "View Result" i see the data of the last processed input. So all "View Result" buttons on the table show same data (of last request).
2. I don't know how to display Pop-up, but can show as a section on bottom of page.

Below is the angularJS function that dynamically generates the "View Result" button.

```
        var Loop = function(i, table) {
               $http({
                   method: "POST",
                   url: "abc.aspx/submit",
                   dataType: 'json',
                   data: { input: table.rows[i].cells[1].innerText,
                       userid: document.getElementById("txtUserid").value,
                       env: $scope.selectedValue
                   },
                   headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
               }).then(function successCallback(response) {

                  $scope.result = JSON.parse(response.data.d);

                  var btnhtml = '<button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs my-xs-btn" type="button" ng-click="resultPopup(result)">View Result</button>';
                  var temp = $compile(btnhtml)($scope);
                   angular.element(table.rows[i].cells[2]).replaceWith(temp)

               }, function errorCallback(response) {


                   table.rows[i].cells[2].innerText = "Failure";

                   table.rows[i].cells[2].title = response.data.d;

               });
```

Section to handle button click event

```
           $scope.resultPopup = function(jsonResult) {


               //var temp = $compile(htmltext)($scope);
               $window.alert(jsonResult);

               //console.log('opening pop up');
               document.getElementById('sec3').style.display = 'block';
               $scope.dynamicRPCresult = jsonResult;
           }

       });
```

Comment: It is always better to create a plnkr or jsfiddle, so that it helps people to provide a solution.

Comment: You're doing it all wrong. Don't do DOM manipulation in the controller. Don't generate and compile HTML in the controller. Create an array of records in your controller. In the template, use ng-repeat to display each record. When the response for a record comes back, change the state of that record, and use that state in the template to hide or display the button, using ng-if. The ng-click of the button should look like `displayRecord(record)`.

Comment: Thank you. I just tried using array and it worked. I modified as below. Now let me see how DOM Manipulation can be put out of controller.                var btnhtml = '<button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs my-xs-btn" type="button" ng-click="resultPopup(result[' + count + '])">View Result</button>';